# Can't run Spark

Tags: java, python, apache-spark

A few days ago I extracted Spark on my machine (Ubuntu) and made a test run, everything seemed fine. Today, I think I changed some Java paths, now Spark won't start.
 Instead I get the following error message:

```
user@user:~/Software/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4$ ./bin/pyspark
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
/home/user/Software/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-class: line 180: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun/bin/bin/java: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Software/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 44, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PySparkShell", pyFiles=add_files)
  File "/home/user/Software/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/context.py", line 104, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway)
  File "/home/user/Software/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/context.py", line 211, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway()
  File "/home/user/Software/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 71, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception(error_msg)
Exception: Launching GatewayServer failed with exit code 127!
Warning: Expected GatewayServer to output a port, but found no output.
```

Running Java programs with Eclipse still works.

**Edit:**

```
which java: /usr/bin/java
javac -version: javac 1.7.0_65
echo $JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun/bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error messages includes path `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun/bin/bin/java`. Notice the duplicated `bin` fragment.

`bin` must not be part of `JAVA_HOME`, set it to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-sun/`.